# Taking the max from multiple Counters instead of adding them up - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, max, counter

**How else to "combine" multiple `Counter` but only taking the maximum value for each key for the "combined" Counter?**

Given a couple of Counters as such:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter([('a'), ('a', 'bc'), ('a', 'bc'), ('xyz', 'hooli')])
>>> y = Counter([('a'), ('a'), ('a'), ('asd', 'asd')])
```

I could do this to add them up:

```
>>> x + y
Counter({'a': 4, ('a', 'bc'): 2, ('asd', 'asd'): 1, ('xyz', 'hooli'): 1})
```

But if my aim is to get combine the Counters but if they have the same key, the goal is **NOT to add** the values up but instead **take the max** of it. **How do I do so?**

I've tried the following code:

```
>>> z = Counter()
>>> for c in [x,y]:
...     for k in c:
...             z[k] = max(z.get(k,0), c[k])
... 
>>> z
Counter({'a': 3, ('a', 'bc'): 2, ('asd', 'asd'): 1, ('xyz', 'hooli'): 1})
```

But is there other way to achieve the same output?

Comment: Counters intuitively should not have this functionality, and don't appear to. Open to other data structures?

Comment: Sure, any data structure that can be casted back into a Counter should be feasible. As long as the data structure has same or lesser overhead than Counter.

Comment: From the docs *Intersection and union return the minimum and maximum of corresponding counts*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Counter` union operator (`|`) returns the maximum counts:

```
>>> x | y
Counter({'a': 3, ('a', 'bc'): 2, ('xyz', 'hooli'): 1, ('asd', 'asd'): 1})
```

Comment: That's awkward, I was just on https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html and missed the line: >>> c | d                       # union:  max(c[x], d[x])
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2})